# R data.table "j" reference to "by" variables very unintuitive?

Tags: r, reference, data.table

I'm just doing the data.table datacamp excercises and there is something which really disturbes my sense for logic. 
Somehow columns which are refered to by the "by" operator are treated different to other columns?

The used data table is the following:

```
         DT
      x  y  z
   1: 2  1  2
   2: 1  3  4
   3: 2  5  6
   4: 1  7  8
   5: 2  9 10
   6: 2 11 12
   7: 1 13 14
```

When I enter DT[,sum(x),x] I would expect:

```
   x V1
1: 2  8
2: 1  3
```

but I get:

```
   x V1
1: 2  2
2: 1  1
```

for other columns I get the group sum as I would expect it:

```
> DT[,sum(y),x]
      x V1
   1: 2 26
   2: 1 23
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It's more a matter of style than finding a work-around. But yours seems very straight forward.

Comment: The docs say ".BY is a list containing a length 1 vector for each item in `by`" and that applies to all columns appearing in `by` as well. You could do `x*.N` to get the sum, too.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this would be to name the grouping variable with a different name

```
setnames(DT[, sum(x), .(xN=x)], "xN", "x")[]
#   x V1
#1: 2  8
#2: 1  3
```